# iOS UITableView with full height in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to have some controls (labels, inputs) and TableView in ScrollView (I have table at bottom). So when user is scrolling that first there are hidden controls at top and then are shown items at their place and then first items are hidden and next are shown etc.

I created this code:

```
if(self.searchResultsTableView.frame.size.height != self.searchResultsTableView.contentSize.height)
        {
            CGRect newFrame = self.searchResultsTableView.frame;
            newFrame.size = self.searchResultsTableView.contentSize;
            self.searchResultsTableView.frame = newFrame;
            mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, self.searchResultsTableView.frame.origin.y + newFrame.size.height);

        }
```

in this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Height is calculated right and it's working but I have problem with some cells. It shows just cell which are loaded and visible without scrolling and when I am trying to scroll I am scrolling but next cells aren't visible. I must tap a few times on button to reload cells to get them visible and then I see them and everything works.

I guess this could be problem because some lazy loading or something like that. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**set your tableview scrolling disable
and set your scrollview content size as your table height.**

Answer (score 0):

Try use `willDisplayCell` instead `cellForRow`.